# Bootstrap-Table filterBy Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am trying to do some filtering (using [bootstrap-table by wenzhixin](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/)) on a table I have being populated via JSON.

**Part of HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="filterBtn">Filter</button>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="make">Make</th>
            <th data-field="model">Model</th>
            <th data-field="year">Year</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Part of JS:**

```
// JSON file is input from a successful AJAX call.
function populateTable(json) {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: json
    })
}

// a button is click in html which calls this function.
function filterBy(model) {
    console.log("filterBy is called");
    $('#table').bootstrapTable('filterBy', {
        make: [model]
    });
}
```

The table populates correctly with all the data but once I hit the button I see that `filterBy()` is called but all that happens is it looks like the page refreshes but all the data in the table is still there like no filtering ever occurred.

I've tried changing `make: [model]` to `make: ["Honda"]` just as a test and it still doesn't work. It still performs the same behavior of refreshing the page with all the data still in tact.

Not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: you could use a data table [ https://datatables.net/ ] , which provides many useful methods (filter() is one of them). It will make things way easier for you

Answer (score 2):

**https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/commit/de867d379a46b377efa7eef83fdf898b9073b28c**

This is an issue i think after feature version: 1.11.0. Check the bootstrap-table.js and find this. I hope its will solve your problem. Good Luck!